# Generating yaml file from template in python

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have a python script queries an api and returns a few different values. From this I'm trying to generate an ansible playbook with the values inserted from an jinja2 template, which looks like this

```
- name: prep change
  hosts: {{ device }}
  gather_facts: no 
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: run arista cmd
    eos_command:
     commands: show ip bgp neighbor | i {{ ip }}
```

*device* and *ip* are values returned from the api call in the python script. Does python allow a jinja2 template be used to create a .yml file?

Comment: I'm not sure whats's the question. Is your plan to render the playbook with jinja? 
Of course jinja2 can render a yam file, but ist a bit tricky due to spaces etc.

Maybe the uri module is better for you: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/uri_module.html

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate that this is not answering your specific question, but if your python script is for the purposes of collecting the necessary data to generate the playbook, and it is not possible just to incorporate calls to the API directly in your playbook, could you consider turning your python script into an Ansible Inventory script?

When you run `ansible_playbook.yml -i /path/to/inventory/dir playbook.yml`, if the files within the directory are executable, Ansible will execute and accept correctly formatted output as the inventory data for your playbook. This way you could make your playbook static, and feed it the data it needs via the dynamic inventory.

Docs are [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts), plus a couple of example blog posts [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2016/12/04/writing-a-custom-ansible-dynamic-inventory-script/) and [here](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/creating-custom-dynamic-inventories-ansible).